# What data type does memory see when I use void?

Tags: c#, c++

When I create a method of type int the compiler reserves X number of bits in memory. So how does the see a void type? How many bits/bytes does a void type take up?

Comment: Are you talking about the return value from a function?

Comment: Did nobody else read the question?  He says 'method of type int' I assume he means a 'method returning an int'.  He doesn't ask how much space a void pointer takes up.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the void type does not take any bits. you cannot declare a variable of type void. this:

```
void a;
```

causes a compilation error.
void is just a place holder that means "nothing" a function that returns void returns nothing and a function that takes void as an argument, takes no arguments.

You can however declare a variable of type void*:

```
void* a;
```

This simply declares a pointer that can point to anything what so ever. as any pointer, it takes the size of a pointer type, i.e. sizeof(void*) which typically equals 4 in 32 bit systems.

Comment: I don't think he's talking about variables, but function signatures.

Answer (score 3):

I think the assumption you made about how a compiler stores return values might be too generic.  What happens with return values is determined by the language, the type, and the hardware.

There might be a 'return register' that could hold the value of the return, so no memory would be taken up.  The 'return register' could also just point to some allocated in memory based on the type being returned.

I don't see why a function returning void would ever have allocated memory for the return value.

Answer (score 3):

On an x86 architecture (using gcc 3.4.6,) the return value of int functions is stored in the eax register. Floating-point numbers are returned via an XMM register or in ST0. [Edit: Thanks Bastien Leonard!]

Void functions simply don't put anything into eax and return.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f1(void)
{
    printf("f1\n");
    return 9.0f;
}
void f2(void)
{
    printf("f2\n");
}

double f3(void)
{
    return 10.0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = f1();
    f2();
    double y = f3();
    return 0;
}
```

builds with gcc -S to:

```
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    movl    $0, %eax
    addl    $15, %eax
    addl    $15, %eax
    shrl    $4, %eax
    sall    $4, %eax
    subl    %eax, %esp
    call    f1
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
    call    f2
    call    f3
    fstpl   -16(%ebp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 3.4.6"
```

with f2 defined:

```
f2:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $8, %esp
    subl    $12, %esp
    pushl   $.LC1
    call    printf
    addl    $16, %esp
    leave
    ret
    .size   f2, .-f2
```

and f1 defined:

```
f1:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $8, %esp
    subl    $12, %esp
    pushl   $.LC0
    call    printf
    addl    $16, %esp
    movl    $9, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

If other people get different code from different versions of gcc, that would be interesting to see XD (Maybe in other situations int functions return on the stack...)

I would imagine that in all implementations, though, a void function simply returns nothing. It either leaves the return registers alone and/or drops nothing on (or into) the stack.

Comment: On x86 and x86_64 platforms on linux, int functions will never use the stack to return. Try returning a long long on x86, or a large struct (or class) on any platform if you want to see returns on the stack.

Comment: @ParoXoN: float and double are returned in ST0 or an XMM register (in your code f3's returned value is retrieved with FSTP, which "pops" ST0).

Answer (score 2):

It the function returns `void`, the caller doesn't expect any return value and nothing needs to be allocated. `void` isn't a real type to be returned, it's more an indication to the compiler that the function returns nothing.

On PC, functions return simple values like `int` by placing them in a particular register (`eax`); the compiler simply generates the appropriate code to retrieve this value. (And if the function returns `void`, then the compiler doesn't generates this kind of code.)
On other architectures, the caller might implicitly pass a parameter pointing to an `int` where the return value will be placed.

This kind of low-level stuff isn't specified by the C and C++ standards. It may be specified by another standard, or it may be just a convention.

For C#, I guess that the answer lies in how you get a return value in [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

Answer (score 1):

There is no void type per se in C or C++ (I don't know anything about C#). void * is a typeless pointer.

This might be of some help: http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidparith.html

Comment: I don't think he's talking about variables, but function signatures.

Comment: malloc returns a void * ... That is a generic pointer to the area of memory allocated with the call. In C, conversion from void * to other types of pointer is automatic. The size of the memory pointed to by the returned pointer is the size which was specified as the argument to malloc.

There is still no void data type. Used in the argument list, it specifies that the function takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an undefined pointer type, so the size is the size of any other pointer on the system you're creating it on.